# How can I access a Controller's class variable in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter

I'm basically trying to cache tweets in my Rails 3 app so I don't have to get them on every page refresh. I have two class variables:

```
@@tweet_time = Time.now
@@tweets = Twitter.user_timeline(TWEET_ACCOUNT)[0,NUMBER_OF_TWEETS]
```

Those are in my controller.

In the controller, I check to see if

```
@@tweet_time < 1.hour.ago
```

and if so I reset @@tweets and @@tweet_time.

But when I try to loop through @@tweets in the view, it says @@tweets is an uninitialized class variable. I guess that is because technically it is being called from ActionView instead of ActionController.

How can I access @@tweets in the view?

PS If I am doing this completely backwards, feel free to critique and hopefully offer me a better way. I really do appreciate any feedback you can offer.

Comment: rails is stateless, how do you cache class variables?

Comment: This is what memcache is for.

Comment: Jakub, you are right. Can you put that in an answer for me? In order to use Memcache, do I *have* to set it up as the Rails caching mechanism, or can I use it outside of that structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the "dalli" gem to do this now. It is a speedy way to use MemCache from what I can tell.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that class variables in the controller will persist across requests. That's not the duty of the controller.

If you don't want to use an in-memory database like Redis to cache your tweets, you can try moving your class variable to a model which you can then query from the controller.

Comment: You are right.  Neither class variables, or any other variables  persist across requests.  Definitely need something like Redis or Memcached here....